# Programmatically set brightness of a PointLight

Tags: lighting, udk

I'm a beginner, so there is definitely something I'm missing here. I'm trying to set brightness of my PointLight object from the in-game command line.

Here is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
class MyCustomGameInfo extends GameInfo;

exec function myTest(float brightness)
{
    local PointLight pointLightOut;
    local PointLight pointLight;

    foreach AllActors( class 'PointLight', pointLightOut )
    {
        pointLight = pointLightOut;
    }

    pointLight.LightComponent.SetLightProperties(brightness);
    pointLight.LightComponent.UpdateColorAndBrightness();
}

defaultproperties
{
}
```

So when I compile it, go to my UDK project, run it, press tab and start typing myTest, the command line autocomlpete works perfectly, and even shows the float parameter. However, it doesn't work. I have a feeling that the way I'm retrieving the object is wrong.

Comment: As it stands, your code will only update to last PointLight found in the scene. You should move the lines setting and updating the brightness to loop. If you only have one light this might not be your problem.

Comment: Yeah, this is just temporary code, just a test. There is only one pointlight on the scene.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a dynamic light? If the light is completely static, I *think* all of the lighting information is going to be baked into the map, so it won't be modifiable at runtime.

Also, you can try logging out the value of `pointLight` to make sure it's both valid, and the correct light actor.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not working on it anymore, but it definitely seems like a possible cause. The light was indeed static.